# Stop SQL returning the same result twice in a JOIN

Tags: sql

I have joined together several tables to get data i want but since I am new to SQL i can't figure out how to stop data being returned more than once.

her's the SQL statement;

```
SELECT
   T.url,
   T.ID,

   S.status,
   S.ID,

   E.action,
   E.ID,
   E.timestamp

FROM tracks T, status S, events E
WHERE S.ID AND T.ID = E.ID

ORDER BY E.timestamp DESC
```

The data that is returned is something like this;

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| URL | ID | Status | ID | action               | ID | timestamp |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| T.1 | 4  | hello  | 4  | has uploaded a track | 4  | time      |
| T.2 | 3  | bye    | 3  | has some news        | 3  | time      |
| t.1 | 4  | more   | 4  | has some news        | 4  | time      |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

That's a very basic example but does outline what happens. If you look at the third row the URL is repeated when there is a different status.

This is what I want to happen;

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| URL or Status | ID | action               | timestamp |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| T.1           | 4  | has uploaded a track | time      |
| hello         | 3  | has some news        | time      |
| bye           | 4  | has some news        | time      |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Please notice that the the url (in this case the mock one is T.1) is shown when the action is has uploaded a track. This is very important. The action in the events table is inserted on trigger of a status or track insert. If a new track is inserted the action is 'has uploaded a track' and you guess what it is for a status. The ID and timestamp is also inserted into the events table at this point.

**Note:** There are more tables that go into the query, 3 more in fact, but I have left them out for simplicity.

Comment: Since you are new to SQL, you shoudl know that implicit joins are a SQL antipattern and you should learn to use explicit joins instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use 20 year out of date syntax.  Although many RDBMS support `FROM a, b, c` style syntax it has been deprecated by all systems that I've worked with.  *(I haven't worked with everything, but it's really strongly advisable to not use this style.)*

Instead use ANSI-92 standard `JOIN` syntax.  Then it's much harder to get things wrong...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  status S
INNER JOIN
  tracks T
    ON T.ID = S.ID
INNER JOIN
  events E
    ON E.ID = S.ID
ORDER BY
  E.timestamp DESC
```

Also, you example data suggest that you have the following in table S...

```
 Status | ID
--------+----
 hello  | 4
 bye    | 3
 more   | 4
```

`ID = 4` has two rows.  If you really want each row in T to only join on one row in S, which row should you pick?  Should one be deleted, or do you have some other logic/condition that you can use to pick one of the two?

Comment: I would upvote you a million itimes if I coudl. Ther is literally no excuse for strill using implict syntax. However, it isnot deprecated in all systems. In SQL Server only the outer join implict syntax has been deprecated (and it never worked proerly anyway which is part of why). People new to SQl need to understand joins and implict joins are far more likely espcially for beginners to be incorrect.

Comment: `FROM a, b, c` is still taught and used. This also does not solve the OP's desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the info, didn't realise it had been deprecated. The tutorial I am using was using the old stuff. Because it's all being returned in a news feed every status from that ID should be returned and then ordered by timestamp.

Comment: @njk - Please read the part that points out that `S.ID = 4` consists of two rows?  It states that additional logic is needed to determine which row to join on *(Or, perhaps the example is incorrect?  or, perhaps the data neads cleanign up?)*

Comment: @Dems if you read the comment from the OP in my answer, the OP does not know how they will determine whether to use `status` vs `url`.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
WHERE S.ID AND T.ID = E.ID
```

To this

```
WHERE S.ID = E.ID AND T.ID = E.ID
```

**Update**

There are some individuals that are extremely touchy feely about using implicit join notation. To appease these individuals and as better practice, you should use explicit `JOIN` statements.

Comment: That does not have the desired effect. Not too sure how to explain it but please look at what the result should look like to explain what needs to happen

Comment: Try `WHERE T.ID = S.ID AND S.ID = E.ID`

Comment: Aha, so what is the logic for determining to use the `status` rather than the `url`?

Comment: Don't use `FROM a, b, c WHERE x` at all.  Use `INNER JOIN`.  Ansi-92 is nearly 20 years old.  Even RDBMS that support `,` notation have deprecated it and advise against using it.  Don't do it.

Comment: I really have no idea. Ideally it would be good to rename the row `url or status` to something like `data` and then the appropriate data could be easily manipulated in PHP. I would use if statements to determine what the action is and do the appropriate commands.

Comment: I will downvotge anyone who encourages beginners to use the implict syntax. It is SQL antipattern and we shoudl avoid recommending teh use of an antipattern.

Comment: @HLGEM I don't see how correcting syntax is encouraging the use of it. That would be equivalent to down voting because someone didn't combine two lines of `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

try using group by;

```
SELECT T1.url, T1.id, S1.estatus, S1.id, E1.action, E1.id, E1.timestamp FROM t T1, s S1, e E1 WHERE S1.id AND T1.id = E1.id GROUP BY S1.id ORDER BY E1.timestamp DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers, they helped a lot. I have made a query that works and manipulated the outcome with if statements in PHP.

Here it is;

```
SELECT 
T.url AS track_url,

S.status,

E.action,
E.ID,
E.timestamp,

A.name,
A.url AS artist_url

FROM events E

LEFT JOIN 
TRACKS T
ON T.ID = E.ID AND E.action = 'has uploaded a track.'

LEFT JOIN  
STATUS S
ON S.ID = E.ID AND E.action = 'has some news.'

LEFT JOIN 
ARTISTS A
ON A.ID = E.ID

ORDER BY E.timestamp DESC
```

The outcome of it is lots of `NULL` columns but that's fine as it works! IF the `ID` hasn't uploaded a track the relevant columns are `NULL` and the same applies to the other bits of the query. The `ID` is not repeated as only the `ID` in the events table is selected.

If you see any problems that I may have overlooked please shout about it!