# Return records when table is not empty

Tags: mysql, sql, date, between

I am brand new to SQL and can only do the most basic of SQL queries and appreciate any help with this problem.

MySQL database contains a CUSTOMER table and a PURCHASES table.  If the customer has made a purchase there will be one or more serial numbers and a purchase date in the PURCHASES table.

I would like to know how to return the customer name, serial number and date of purchase for each customer who has made a purchase between two dates.

Here is a description of the tables:

PURCHASES

- customer_id
- serial_number
- purchase date

CUSTOMER

- customer_id
- customer_name
- customer address

Comment: have you noticed that you have inconsistency in your structure? why one table is called CUSTOMER while the second is PURCHASES? use singular or plural consistently, otherwise you will have hard times remembering when you used plural and when singular form

Comment: Heh. I just noticed I got my query wrong for exactly that reason :-(

Answer (score 3):

Here it is:

```
select c.customer_name, p.serial_number, p.purchase
from purchases p, customers c
where p.customer_id = c.customer_id and
p.purchase between '2012-08-27' and '2012-08-31'
```

The SQL Fiddle is here so that you can play with it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8002/3

Comment: How do you feel about implicit joins? I got [railed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12217895/679449) this morning about them.

Comment: I see... no problem to me as long as the query returns the correct/expected result! I always liked to use this fashion with simple queries. They look more SIMPLE and readable this way.

Comment: @njk I think if you're not going to use the ANSI-92 join syntax, you shouldn't be allowed to use any other language feature introduced after that date :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to `JOIN` the two tables; see MySQL documentation for the joining concept.

You need to limit the query on purchases between the two dates:

```
WHERE purchase BETWEEN 'date1' AND 'date2'
```

and this will tell you the customer ID. With this you select into the Customers table, so:

```
SELECT customer.customer_name,
       purchases.serial_number,
       purchases.purchase
    FROM customer
    JOIN purchases ON (customer.customer_id = purchases.purchase_id)
    WHERE purchases.purchase BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-08-01';
```